# Create a route with an additional url parameter without creating an area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm building a site for a client using .Net MVC 4. The entire site uses the default MVC 4 route and all the pages work fine

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        )
```

There is a page on the site called 'Teachers'.  For this page, there are several links that take you to new pages that are subsets of the 'Teachers' page.  The client wants the url structure to appear like this

www.{mysite}.com/School/Teachers/Apply

www.{mysite}.com/School/Teachers/Benefits

I thought I could simple add the Apply and Benefits pages as an ActionResult in my SchoolController then use the routing feature in MVC to map the url to the correct ActionResult method in the SchoolController.

This is my controller:

```
public class SchoolController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Administration()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Teachers()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Apply()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Benefits()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This is the custom route that I tried.

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "Teachers",
       "{controller}/{page}/{action}",
       new { controller = "School", page = "Teachers", action = "Index" }
           )
```

I placed this route before the default route but this adds 'teachers' to every url on the site like this:

www.{mysite}.com/{controller}/teachers/{action}

**SUMMARY**

All the pages on my site use this url structure:

> www.{mysite}.com/{controller}/{action}

This one page, however, has the following structure:

> www.{mysite}.com/{controller}/teachers/{action}

How can I do this with routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "TeachersActions",
        url: "School/Teachers/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "School" },
        constraints: new { action = "Apply|Benefits" } // actions under Teachers
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",
                        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Any actions you want to be under Teachers should be added to the route.  It is actually not necessary to specify defaults for action or page for this route to work (unless you do have some need for a page route value to be captured).  The catch here is that a user can still target the actions under Teachers by entering the URL `School/{action}` because it is caught by the default route.  Now this may or may not be a concern for you.  Personally I would not consider it such a big issue since the users should just be using the site's navigation instead of entering the URLs manually.

Comment: Route order is important, this route will only work if it is *before* the default route.

Comment: @ErikPhilips That is correct, this route is very specific and they did state they had placed their route before the default.

Comment: @asymptoticFault I tried your new answer. All the other controllers are working normally.  The only problem now is that the url for the other ActionResults in my Teachers controller look like this: www.mysite.com/school/teachers/teachers/

Comment: It is still adding Teachers before all the other ActionResults in the School controller

Comment: Most likely correct, I haven't thought about how that would affect the UrlHelper to produce urls nor the @Html.ActionLink and other HtmlHelper actions that produce urls.  You can definitely update the answer with your comment in mind.

Comment: I updated my route to match yours and I also updated my Controller above to include the other Index and Administration methods in the controller.  What's happening now when I make a request for those two methods is I get www.mysite.com/school/teachers/(method).  So it is including Teachers in the urls for all requests handled by the School Controller.

Comment: Ok I think I figured out the solution you are looking for. Check the updated answer. It requires altering the route with a constraint to only target the specified actions to be under Teachers.